# PHP multi level authorization

Tags: php, mysql, authorization, access-control, abac

[explained matter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GduOF.jpg)

i have made a system for a company that they have several branches in other provinces. 
every branches are apart from one another the boss of this company asked to us that don't allow branch_1 manager to see or control the data of branch_2 and inverse of it. like this through all branches. 
each branch has multiple employees and each employee of one branch can insert the relevant data of that branch and employees can't have other controls on data. 
i have made the system by pure PHP and MySQL.
eventually i want a good way to proceed this project.

Comment: And you clearly want all the data in the same tables in the same database? Normally I would suggest giving each branch a separate database. It is the best way to assure absolute separation, and it is simple.

Comment: @ KIKO Software But it is difficult to get data of whole organization if branch have different database

Comment: i know this, but the customer the boss wants his all data integrated in one place. thanks KIKO software.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with user table in database by define user_role, is_super_admin, default_branch_id etc. and control user by save default_branch_id in session.

- As you save branch_id in session. Then when a user of branch_1 login then he will able to see branch_1 data.
- By define user_role_id in user table you can give different permission to different  user. For example:

  ```
  role_id=1 means Super Admin. He has control all over the system.
  role_id=2 means Admin. He has control on a single branch.
  role_id=3 means HR. He has see report only`
  ```

For role wise privilege you can read tutorial on [role wise privilege in php](https://www.thesoftwareguy.in/creating-multi-user-role-based-admin-using-php-mysql-bootstrap/) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=role+wise+privilege+in+php)